# Fix build vNext after collection move

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

I moved a team project collection to a new server. Everything is fine in Visual Studio and the web site, but the build is trying to retrieve source code form the old server.

In the build definition I see no place to set the collection URI. There is a `System.TeamFoundationCollectionUri` variable but it's read only, trying to set it in Variables causes an `An item with the same key has already been added.` error on build.

Trying to add a new mapping in Repository works so the (web/app) server is aware that the source code moved, but the old location seems to be left somewhere in the build definition.

Is there any way to fix that? Without re-creating all build definitions I mean.

Comment: Did you re-register the build agent to the new server?

Comment: Yes. The agents are there, and the builds are triggered by CI, but the agents are looking for source code on the old server.

Comment: How did you move the collection?

Comment: Detach / move / re-attach. There is no documentation for 2015 on MSDN, I followed the 2013 one https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/dd936138(v=vs.120).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing visible in the web interface, but you can see the server name in the TFS SQL database. The column Repository is a nvarchar(MAX) containing all the mappings **and the server name**.

I fixed the server name with a replace in SQL and it works now.